# helptext for create table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Can I get the whole query which I used for creating a table, like we have sp_helptext to get the query of a stored procedure.

`sp_helptext 'procedure_name'`

Is there anything like this available for create table also in SQL server express?

I want to view the whole query which I wrote for creating a particular table and not the table structure.

Like if a deleted a table, and again want to create it, then I would have to type the whole query again, so I want a way through which I don't have to write the whole query again, like in mysql there is an option such as SHOW, which shows the table query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en) you can right-click on a table in the Object Explorer window and choose to generate the CREATE script into a new query window or put it in the clipboard or save it in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try [sp_columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms176077%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) or [sp_help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187335%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx). But this will not give you the `CREATE TABLE` text, you have to create this text for yourself.

You can also have a look at [Catalog Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182764%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)